# How to get ALSA to trigger events for USB audio volume changes on the hardware

Tags: alsa, usb-audio, alsamixer

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and I've even posted a few questions from different angles on it, but I have yet to get a response.  So, if my question is nonsense, please let me know.  If there is something missing that would make this easier to understand, please let me know.

Here is the basic problem.  I've got a RaspPi 5, with a PolyCom P3200M speaker attached to it.  (It is actually for conference calls, so it is mic/speaker in one.)

I want to trigger events if the volume keys on the speaker itself are pressed.

If I run `amixer -Dsysdefault:2 sset PCM Playback 5` for example, it will indeed set the volume on the speaker hardware to that level.

If I run `amixer -Dsysdefault:2 events`, and then issue in a separate term `amixer -Dsysdefault:2 sset PCM Playback 5`, the events are indeed captured.

However, if, instead, I push the volume buttons on the speaker, the volume on the speaker will change, but no event is triggered for `amixer` to react to.

Can this be done?  Can I trigger an event on `amixer events` when I push the volume buttons on the speaker?  Is there another way to get to the same end point of knowing when the buttons are pressed?